# How to split a single row into multiple rows, each with their own cell values for the differing columns in Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in excel that includes this information for example, with each row tied to one account in image 1. How would i split the table in image 1 without manually inserting rows and showcasing one price for each row, like that of image 2?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I'd suggest using Power Query or VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

1. Select the Range- go to Data- From Table/Range- open Power Query editor:
   [image]
2. Select Price 1, Price 2, Price 3 columns- go to Transform- select Unpivot Columns- go to Add Column- select Index Column and click From 1:
   [image]
3. Select Attribute, Value columns- go to Transform- Select Value Colum: Value- Remove Index column- go to Home and select Close and Load:
   [image]

Comment: is there a way to maintain the table design format? when i transform it, it turns into a green table and i want the table to look blue with banded rows. I also have accounts in red font and i want the query to preserve the same table fill/colour, date, currency, and column header colour properties after running the query.

Comment: You need to design the table yourself.

Comment: ok, the only solution i can think of is manually using format painter from the old table to the pivoted table for each column

Comment: Late to the game, but if you right-click the table, select "External Data Properties" make sure "Preserve Cell Formatting" is on (and I usually prefer unchecking "Adjust Column Width", but there are reasons to leave that on sometimes), Apply the table formatting design you like, and refreshing will not change it.